# Angular issues with Bootstrap components

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-5

I'm building a site using angular 12, I don't think is relevant but I'm using sccs.
I have a problem with using the bootstrap module, for example with dropdown, modal and tooltips, which are basically the components I need most.
I installed the bootstrap module using 'npm install bootstrap'.
My scripts array is configured like this:

```
"scripts": [ 
"node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js", 
"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" ]
```

the code of the dropdown that I'm trying to use is:
**https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/dropdowns/**

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Action
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Does the button appear as like in Bootstrap?

Comment: yeah, it appears like in bootstrap but at the click nothing happen

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just import Popperjs twice that causing the problem so removing popperjs and bootstrap.min.js imports will solve your problem else follow below given steps

Steps to use bootstrap in Angular.

1. Install bootstrap

   - `npm install bootstrap --save`
2. In **angular.json** file

   - Under **styles array** import **bootstrap.min.css**

     - `"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"`
   - Under **scripts array** import **bootstrap.bundle.min.js** file because popper.js is included in bootstrap.bundle.js file. If you import **bootstrap.js** only then you must have to import **popper.js** before **bootstrap.js** For More Information [Check Bootstrap Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/contents/)

     - `"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"`

[Angular.json file content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX4NN.png)

**For Jquery**

1. If you want to use jquery also then import jquery before **bootstrap.bundle.min.js**.
2. Install jquery types from npm

   - `npm install --save @types/jquery`
3. In **angular.json** file import jquery

   - `"node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"`
4. In **tsconfig.app.json** file add jquery type under **compilerOptions**

   - `"types": ["jquery"]`
5. Then use jquery famous $ variable
6. Enjoy

[jsconfig.app.json file content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFVT7.png)

**UPDATE**

If you're using scss then import bootstrap scss files in styles array instead of css files.

In your **angular.json** file under style array import bootstrap scss files
`node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss`

Comment: it depends on which version they're using bootstrap 5 uses vanilla javascript.  

the op should post his button the html, and the typescript so we can see what's going on.  if the button is appearing - do you have a (click) function assigned to it?  are you using it as a routerLink?

Comment: @chrisburd actually the problem is in import files. He imports popperjs twice. One from @popper/core and the other from bootstrap.bundle.min.js. Removing bootstrap.bundle.min.js OR [popperjs and bootstrap.min.js] both will solve the problem

Comment: @FaizShahid i did everything you wrote before doing this post, only the style works, i think the js for some reason is not loaded

Comment: @GiuseppeParisi this is because you import popperjs twice. just keep jquery and then bootstrap.bundle.min.js in scripts array else all others, remove them

Comment: @FaizShahid i changed my angular.json like you said but the problem still persist, now my scripts array is like this
"scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            ]

Comment: @GiuseppeParisi Edit your question and paste the code that causing problem

Comment: I edited the question, hope you can help me

Comment: All the info is in my answer. Please read below. Bootstrap cannot do anything based on those classes in your component HTML because Bootstrap has already done it's things before the Angular app is even bootstrapped (pun intended).

Comment: @GiuseppeParisi I edit my answer. Kindly check

Answer (score -3):

Angular components are created dynamically so any script that's doing things to elements on page load, don't automatically do anything when used in Angular templates.

With a little bit of searching, you would find libraries for using Bootstrap on Angular, such as: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235700/discussion-on-answer-by-funkizer-angular-issues-with-bootstrap-components).